# How does the recursive function in Quicksort Algorithm works?

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

First of all, I've been searching for the answer for this question but I still haven't found the simple and straight to the point answer.

Anyway, I'm about to understand how Quicksort algorithm works, I have understood how its partition works and why it is one of the best sorting algorithm. But since I am new in recursive functions (i know only the basic), I couldn't understand how this code below works.

```
    static public void SortQuick(int[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        // For Recursion  
        if (left < right)
        {
            int pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

            // This "if statement" is for left partition (correct me if i'm wrong)
            if (pivot > 1)
            {
                SortQuick(arr, left, pivot - 1);
            }

            // And this "if statement" is for right partition (again, correct me if i'm wrong)
            if (pivot + 1 < right)
            {
                SortQuick(arr, pivot + 1, right);
            }
        }
    }
```

I used Visual Studio breakpoints in order to understand its recursion but I'm still confused. I am confused why when I change the second "if" statement into "else if" the output of it is changing and I am confused how the recursion ends.

P.S: I didn't put the Partition() method as I have already understood how it works.

Comment: Go through the algorithm, then it will be cleared

Comment: [Check out this site's very clear and thoroughly awesome explanations as to how each sorting algorithm works.](https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer specifically to the second "if" part of the question. It cannot be an "else if". The algorithm reads:

- Can I split your list into a **left half** and a **right half**?
- Do I have a left half? If I do then sort the left half.
- Do I have a right half? If I do a then sort the right half.

The reason why you cannot have an "else if", is you have scenarios where there are both "left half" and "right half" to sort.

In the case where partition finds no smaller lists to sort, the recursion ends naturally.

For further research, I recommend YouTube and Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The Recursion is repeating the process at on smaller and smaller lists until you obtain lists of only a single item.

The two if statements, are checking if the pivot point is the leftmost or rightmost item of the list. When it is the leftmost `pivot =1`, it stops making lists on the left. When it is the rightmost `pivot+1 = right`, it stops making lists on the right.

When you reach a single item (both leftmost an rightmost) it will stop breaking it down any further.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this site](http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/), for step by step processing of a Quick-Sort algorithm.

> why `if` and not `else if`

It is because after fixing an element in its correct position we will get a `left sub-array` and a `right sub-array` we need to performs the same operations on both that's why we are taking two separate `if` instead for `else if`

Answer (score 0):

I've done a super-short implementation of it for you to understand. Look:

```
void QuickSort(int arr[], int left, int right){
    int pos = (left + right)/2;                  //get middle position of array
    int pivot = arr[pos];                        //stores the value of pivot
    swap(arr[pos], arr[right]);                  //put pivot in the end of array
    int i = left, j = right- 1;                  //initialize pointers

    while(i <= j){
        while(arr[i] < pivot) i++;               //move left
        while(arr[j] >= pivot && j >= i) j--;    //move right
        if(i < j) swap(arr[i++], arr[j--]);      //swap (and walk) if possible
    }

    swap(arr[i], arr[right]);                    //return pivot to right position
    if(i - left) QuickSort(arr, left, i - 1);    //recursion if left subarray isn't empty
    if(right- i) QuickSort(arr, i + 1, right);   //recursion if right subarray isn't empty
}
```

basically the recursion is used inside the partition function and it is executed always the left and the right subarrays are not empty.